# Using pseudo-elements as list numbers and centering the numbers vertically with respect to the list items

Tags: css

As it says in the title, I'm looking to try to vertically center numbers of an ordered list made with pseudo elements. A setup of the problem is below.

```
<ul class="colored-list">
    <li>
    Here's some text
    </li>
    <li>
    Here's some text, enough of it to spill onto the next line
    </li>    
</ul>
```

---

```
ul.colored-list { list-style: none; max-width: 100px; }
    ul.colored-list > li {counter-increment: step-counter; font-size: 16px;}
    ul.colored-list > li:before { color: red;content: counter(step-counter); font-size: 35px; margin-left: -22px; }
```

---

[jsfiddle.net/dmzv3kd5/](http://jsfiddle.net/dmzv3kd5/)

What I want is the red numbers to be vertically centered with respect to the list items. For example, the "1" should be halfway between the words "Here's" and "text".

Is this possible, and if so, what is the best implementation?

Comment: Is it allowed to alter the markup?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could absolutely position the pseudo-element *relative* to the parent.

Then you can use a combination of `top: 50%`/`transform: translateY(-50%)` for vertical centering.

Rather than resorting to negative margins like `margin-left: -22px`, just use `right: 100%`:

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/xg4cdd21/)

```
ul.colored-list > li {
    position: relative;
    counter-increment: step-counter;
    font-size: 16px;
}
ul.colored-list > li:before {
    color: red;
    content: counter(step-counter);
    font-size: 35px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 100%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try making the list `display: table` and the `:before` `display: table-cell` and then use `vertical-align: middle`. You'll have to play around with your margin and padding. Here you go:

```
ul.colored-list { list-style: none; max-width: 100px; }
    ul.colored-list > li {counter-increment: step-counter; font-size: 16px; display: table; }
    ul.colored-list > li:before { color: red;content: counter(step-counter); font-size: 35px; margin-left: -14px; padding-right: 8px; display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle; }
```

[Forked jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BrettEast/d2faL82c/)